# Xcode 6.1 Main Storyboard turned blank when clicked on Show the Version Editor button

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new and following a tutorial when I misclicked on the "Show the Version Editor" button instead of the Assistant Editor all my graphics I've made in the Main Storyboard is now blank! I can find them in the tree but they are "grey" or "faded", so I can't drag and drop anymore.

I guess it's just a view setting or something but I can't find how to restore it to normal?

Please help, looks like I can't post a screenshot of it since I'm new :(

Thanks

NisseB!

Comment: You probably switched to another size class. Toggle through the size classes at the bottom of the InterfaceBuilder window (i.e: wAny/hAny). Once you find the one you designed your controls in they will reappear.

Comment: Yes this was it! Thanks I saw it now :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself! I just had to change the canvas size to what I had before running the Version Editor (for all iPhones) and then all the objects appeared again! If I also disabled Auto Layout I got some objects back, but in wrong locations, so this was better!